# why did I get "ambigous" error when invoking same-named function in different namespace?

Tags: c++, gcc, syntax-error, argument-dependent-lookup

I implement a function named `make_heap()` in namespace `dsa`. and I get error when I tried to invoke it and `std::make_heap()` to make comparison. GCC told me that:

> call of overloaded 'make_heap(dsa::Vector::iterator&, dsa::Vector::iterator&, std::greater)' is ambiguous

The code is following, any suggestions?

```cpp
template<typename _Random_It>
void make_heap(_Random_It first, _Random_It last)
{
    // get true value_type from the iterators
    using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<_Random_It>::value_type;

    make_heap(first, last, std::greater<value_type>());   // << error here
}

template<typename _Random_It, typename _Comp>
void make_heap(_Random_It first, _Random_It last, _Comp compare)
{
    if(first + 2 >= last)
    {
        return ;
    }

    for(size_t i = (last - first) / 2; i > 0; i--)
    {
        __heapify(first, last, i, compare);
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven’t posted the *complete* code. Do you have `using namespace std;` or similar in your code? — Also, note that your code uses illegal identifiers. You’re not allowed to use `__heapify` or `_Random_It` etc.

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]. I'm gonna guess you have `using namespace std;` somewhere in your code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Wouldn't ADL bring `std::make_heap` into the scope? OP uses `std::greater` as one of the arguments.

Comment: Change `std::greater<value_type>()` to `std::greater<value_type>`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Right, that’s a good point.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What?

Comment: @KonradRudolph all of them is in namespace `dsa` and I never use `using namespace std;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it will be reported as a error if delete `()`, you cannot pass a type as parameter to function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) strikes back:

`make_heap(first, last, std::greater<value_type>());` has as argument `std::greater` which is in `namespace std`, so unqualified name `make_heap` also looks into `namespace std`.

"Solution" is to make qualified name lookup (or use name which don't conflict):

`dsa::make_heap(first, last, std::greater<value_type>());`

Creating your own `dsa::greater` might be a temporary solution, but if users use `make_heap` with iterators "from" `std` (either `std::vector<int>::iterator` (assuming it is not a pointer), or `dsa::vector<std::string>>::iterator`), you would have same issue.

Comment: yes, I knew this solution. But I am confused the effect of namespace, isn't it isolating from other namespace?

Comment: sort of... but ADL is here to do a "bridge". Really useful for operators (as `operator <<`). might be problematic in other cases as yours.